# Reporting Services Chart - X-Axis name problem

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have created a chart using a stored procedure which lists totals by name.

However when I create the chart the names only appear for every second element. I have tested this in a table and I get each name correctly.

My first thoughts were that it was a sizing issue, so I considerably increased the size of my chart, but this doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

[URL=http://img11.imageshack.us/i/rschart.jpg/][IMG]http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/7191/rschart.

Answer (score 5):

That "VariableAutoInterval" did not work for me, it showed every alternate other label. However the following worked:

In the Axis Properties -> Interval, type 1 : This will show every label. If you type 2, it will show every alternate label and so on.

http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/3118/capturerk.png

Reference : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934393.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. If you go to the properties of the X-Axis in your chart and go to >Interval > VariableAutoInterval and by default this is set to false. Set this to true and it now works.

However there is a problem with formatting as although the labels appear they are displayed slighter off centre of the actual bar elements... this should easily be fixed though.

Thanks for your help!

[URL=http://img230.imageshack.us/i/rschart2.jpg/][IMG]http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/3958/rsc

Answer (score 0):

Ahh you have run into the notorious RS bug that most everyone doesn't notice.  No solution to this, however what you can do to display ALL x axis labels is to shorten the categories (or x-axis values to 3-4 letters a piece and display a key).

What I mean about this is in your SQL table of categories add a field called Acronym or something an for a category such as :

SQL SERVER CATEGORY I

In the acronym field make it

SSCI

And in your report instead of using the category field use a much shorter value (the SSCI value).  Now next to your report object just create a matrix / table object that displays categories with their acronyms.  You do realize that you can use multiple objects in one report that may point to different data sets.

Doing this will display all the X-Axis values, it is all because of the lengths of the categories...

Comment: Thanks for the reply John!

In our table structure we actually have ID's associated with the names which are SMALLINT values. I tried the report again using these for the X-Axis (which are at the most two digits in length) just to test but I still have the same problem!!! Grr!!!

Comment: That doesnt make any sense...but whatever does :).
Are you using Dundas add in or just RS?  How big is the chart in size.  Try to expand the report to full page size 8.5 x 11 inch by going into the properties of the report.  Also try to look at the properties of the chart and see if you can format it to add some padding.  Im going to create a test one right now.

Comment: I am using the standard charts in 2008, I haven't used any add-ons. BUT I believe that Microsoft and Dundas collaborated for 2008

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me.  Can you try to export the report to pdf / excel and check the results.  Also I am using RS 2005, are you using 2008?

Comment: Sorry I'm using 2008. I have exported to PDF/Excel and the results are the same... however if i export to CSV I get the full listing of names

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!